# $\frac{\mathrm{d} g(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}=h(x)$ and $\frac{\mathrm{d} h(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}=g(x)$ where $h(x)\neq g(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions

Is there any other solution to :
$$\frac{\mathrm{d} g(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}=h(x)$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d} h(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}=g(x)$$
other than $h(x)=g(x)=e^x$?

By varying $\alpha,\beta$ in

$$\frac{\mathrm{d} g(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}=\alpha h(x)$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d} h(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}=\beta g(x)$$

is it possible to obtain $(e^x,e^x) , (\sin (x),\cos(x))$ as solutions when $\alpha = 1, \beta=1$ and 
$\alpha = 1, \beta=-1$ (without invoking complex analysis) is there any explanation for relationships between $\alpha,\beta$ yielding relationships between $e^x,\sin(x),\cos(x)$?

Comment: This is a linear system, so it can be represented in [matrix form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_differential_equation).

Comment: @Daryl : Is That matrix form equivalent to using complex form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system of differential equations can be written in [matrix form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_differential_equation) as
$$\frac{d\vec{u}}{dx}=A\vec{u},$$
where $$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&\alpha\\\beta&0\end{bmatrix}\text{ and } \vec{u}=\begin{bmatrix}g(x)\\h(x)\end{bmatrix}.$$
The general solution can then be expressed in terms of the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$.

The eigenvalues are $\lambda_{1,2}=\pm\sqrt{\alpha\beta}$ with corresponding eigenvectors
$$\vec{v}_{1,2}=\begin{bmatrix}-\alpha\\\pm\sqrt{\alpha\beta}\end{bmatrix}.$$

The general form of the solution is then given by
$$ \vec{u}(x)=c_1\vec{v}_1e^{\lambda_1 x}+c_2\vec{v}_2e^{\lambda_2 x}.$$

In terms of non-exponential solutions, these can be obtained with complex eigenvalues, i.e. $\alpha\beta<0$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\mathrm{d} g(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}=\alpha h(x),\frac{\mathrm{d} h(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}=\beta g(x)\implies \frac{\mathrm{d^2} g(x)}{\mathrm{d}{x^2}}=\alpha\frac{\mathrm{d} h(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}=\alpha\beta g(x)$$

Let $g(x)=Ae^{at}\implies \frac{\mathrm{d} g(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}=Aae^{at}$ and $ \frac{\mathrm{d^2} g(x)}{\mathrm{d}{x^2}}=Aa^2e^{at}$

So, $$Ae^{at}\alpha\beta= Aa^2e^{at}$$

As $Ae^{at}\ne 0$ for non-trivial solutions, $a^2=\alpha\beta$

So, $g(x)=A_1e^{a_1t}+A_2e^{a_2t}$ where $A_1,A_2$ are arbitrary for constants and $a_1,a_2$ are the roots of $a^2=\alpha\beta$.

If $\alpha=\beta=1, g(x)=A_1e^t+A_2e^{-t}$ as $a^2=1$

If $\alpha=1,\beta=-1;a^2=-1,a=\pm i$ so $g(x)=A_1e^{it}+A_2e^{-it}$
$=(A_1+A_2)\cos t+i(A_1-A_2)\sin t$ using [Euler identity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerFormula.html).

Comment: I bet this generalizes really nicely to $f=af^{(n)}$.

Comment: Your line after "So, ..." is incorrect. It should be $Aae^{at}=\alpha\beta Ae^{at}$, as you substituted $g$ and $g''$ in the wrong places.

Comment: @Daryl, I think you meant $Aa^2e^{at}=\alpha\beta Ae^{at}$ as rectified in the answer?

Comment: +1, but is there an alternative to Euler identity, or is it a fundamental block of math that can not do without? No alternatives in it's place?

Comment: @lab Yes, I missed an index.

Comment: @Arjang, to me this identity is indispensable in  (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation)

Comment: @labbhattacharjee : Yes, but is there a deeper reason for it? Are there alternative (non obvious) forms to it? it seems to be a one of the building blocks that one may as well start with it and derive the rest of mathematics from it. In complex analysis there are five theorems that are all equivalent to each other, i.e. any one of them implies all others, but there is nothing else that is equivalent to Euler's formula.